# Ignore missing sources

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a power query under Excel that merges information from about 30 different sources in CSV and XML format.
Sometimes, some of the sources are unavailable or have errors and all my table is compromised, I can not update it.
Is there a way to ignore missing or damaged sources?
Thank you.

Comment: Look for `try ... otherwise`

Comment: [Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-removerowswitherrors) will remove rows with any errors. 
Because he's using merged sources, a `try` without `otherwise lets you preserve information` like this <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-error-handling#handling-errors> That can be useful in a case like merging REST API results -- knowing whether it's a 403, or 404, or 500 can be important

Comment: there are no rows to remove, the source is unavailable, the server is down

Comment: 1] Make a table with a column of your sources 2] use `Table.AddColumn` where you call  `Web.contents` with that row's url. 3] remove rows that have errors 4] expand column on your parsed response 5]  finished. --- I didn't post  as an answer because you need to edit this some, but you can use it as an example -- [ninmonkeys.com/blog chaining multiple web.contents queries](https://ninmonkeys.com/blog/2021/01/31/power-query-custom-functions-cheat-sheet/#Chaining_WebContents_to_Merge_Many_Queries)